Having trouble authenticating with vault using kubernetes auth: Permission denied
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but after following the documentation for setting up kubernetes auth with vault, it doesn't seem to work.
My steps for setting up vault are as follows:
# install vault
helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com
helm install vault hashicorp/vault -n vault --create-namespace \
  --set "injector.enabled=false" \
  --set "server.dev.enabled=true"

# enable vault kubernetes authentication
kubectl -n vault exec vault-0 -- vault auth enable kubernetes

# configure vault to use kubernetes auth
kubectl -n vault exec vault-0 -- vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
  kubernetes_host=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local \
  disable_local_ca_jwt=true

# create role to authenticate with (use root policy just for testing purposes)
kubectl -n vault exec vault-0 -- vault write auth/kubernetes/role/my-app \
  bound_service_account_names=my-app \
  bound_service_account_namespaces=vault \
  alias_name_source=serviceaccount_name \
  token_policies=root \
  ttl=1h

My app is deployed via helm chart as well, I won't post all the code for that here, but I will show the important bits: The result of helm template on my app shows the following
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-app
automountServiceAccountToken: false
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: vault-token
          projected:
            sources:
              - serviceAccountToken:
                  path: vault-token
                  expirationSeconds: 3600
                  audience: vault
      serviceAccountName: my-app
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: "repo/my-app:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
              name: vault-token

The helm installation works, and I log the jwt from the service account in the container (for debugging). When I decode the jwt it looks like this:
{
  "aud": [
    "vault"
  ],
  "exp": 1724541540,
  "iat": 1724537940,
  "iss": "https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local",
  "jti": "497a8b8e-6cb0-4eb0-966b-3d659ecc4c60",
  "kubernetes.io": {
    "namespace": "vault",
    "node": {
      "name": "ip-10-0-21-203",
      "uid": "8383ada6-253e-4d1a-a2a1-8ab7fd510461"
    },
    "pod": {
      "name": "my-app-55bd645df8-rt6qv",
      "uid": "cf15e767-79de-40ca-ab79-9f64c2f6b25d"
    },
    "serviceaccount": {
      "name": "my-app",
      "uid": "e38db1ee-20a6-4144-a046-e7b8cadff640"
    }
  },
  "nbf": 1724537940,
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:vault:my-app"
}

I then use the jwt to try and authenticate with vault directly (just to test that it works)
kubectl exec vault-0 -n vault -- vault write auth/kubernetes/login role=my-app jwt=$MY_JWT

However, I keep getting the following response

Error writing data to auth/kubernetes/login: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
command terminated with exit code 2


I've been trying to figure out how to make this work but it seems like everything I try results in the same error. Hoping someone can spot my mistake, or point me to a better way of debugging. The audit logs for vault have not been very helpful, they simply say "permission denied" as well.
As far as I can tell from the documentation, my current set up/configuration should work, any idea why this might be failing?
FYI: I am running these commands against a k3s kubernetes cluster.

I looked closer at docs, and found I needed to omit the disable_local_ca_jwt parameter from the vault write auth/kubernetes/config command. After this I was able to successfully authenticate. (also found that "auth methods cannot create root tokens"). But that isn't a concern of mine.
